# SQL Server log for revoke statements

Tags: sql-server-2008, logs

I am trying to figure if **SQL Server** has a feature to log when a user fires statements as revoke, delete from, etc.

It would be great to see which user has fired the command, date and time, and which command has been run.

Is there a way to accomplish this in **SQL Server 2008**?

I have seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: server side trace is your best option to capture sql statements.

Comment: SQL Server does not track this activity by default. You want to consider SQL Server Audit (depending on edition) or trace/extended events.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server does not trace revoke or deletes by default. In order to trace those activities, you need to run a server side trace (or XEvents as Aaron pointed out).

Below trace will help you to find command (Text), start date, end date, login, database (I have filtered it for `test_kin`), and many other fields.

Adjust the filters as per your need and environment. Also, specify how big the trace file would be through `@maxfilesize`.

```
/****************************************************/
/* Created by: SQL Server 2014 Profiler          */
/****************************************************/


-- Create a Queue
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 100

-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'InsertFileNameHere', @maxfilesize, NULL 
if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 11, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 11, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 11, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 4, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 41, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 48, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 50, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 4, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 5, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 29, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 30, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 41, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 49, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 50, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 55, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 60, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 61, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 66, @on


-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 35, 0, 6, N'test_kin'
-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Below is the screen shot :

[image]